# Per-asset versioning

Tags: symfony, assets

Until now I have been using the standard "assets.version" configuration directive for the versioning of my assets. I am releasing a new production quite frequently (once a week or more). So if I change a single asset (e.g. javascript file), I increment my "version counter".

Here is my problem with this system: Changing a single line in an asset causes the invalidation of all assets of the whole application! This means that every weeks, users connecting to my application will re-download all assets! This appear to be quite inefficient to me...

My Question: is there a smarter system? for example we could imagine a console command to execute before each release that would track changes of every assets (using e.g. md5) and save the version to be used for every single asset? This way, only modified assets would be re-downloaded...

I know I can develop my own service and use assets.version_strategy like in [this example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/custom_version_strategy.html) But, before re-inventing the wheel, I would like to know if nothing similar already exists? It seams to me that every one should be using such a solution...

Thank you!

Vincent

Comment: You can but it's a useless micro optimization.

Comment: I think it all depends on how frequently your users are coming back. But saying it is a useless optimization is like saying browsers cache is useless...